# Stop loop and expand active element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this animation 
http://jsfiddle.net/atcr4/7/

```
jQuery("#blue").delay( 1000 ).animate(
        {"height": "+=20px", "width": "+=45px"},
        "slow", function(){
            jQuery(this).css({
                "box-shadow":"1px 3px 3px #333",
                "position":"relative"})

        });

jQuery("#green").delay( 1000 ).animate(
        {"height": "+=20px", "width": "-=45px"},
        "slow", function(){
        });
jQuery("#orange").delay( 1000 ).animate(
        {"height": "-=20px", "width": "+=45px"},
        "slow", function(){
        });
jQuery("#pink").delay( 1000 ).animate(
        {"height": "-=20px", "width": "-=45px"},
        "slow", function(){
        });
```

Is there any way when I hover one of boxes to stop the loop and box that is hovered expand?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use .stop or .finish :

```
jQuery("#blue").hover(function() {
      $( this ).finish();
});
```

or

```
 jQuery("#blue").hover(function() {
      $( this ).stop(true,true);
});
```

Check the API references which suits your intention best:

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

http://api.jquery.com/finish/

Comment: Thank you @Gal Samuel that stopped the loop, but if for example I hover green box I need that box to expand and all other boxes shrinks. If I hover orange that box expand, all other boxes shrinks... Sorry I cant explain it better. My English isn't that good. :)

Comment: You need to set behavior for each box by ID or for a specific class by class name. That can do the trick.